# Maven using Android Library project with ADT

Tags: android, maven, adt

How can i use Maven to successfully configure android library type project under Android Development Toolkit

I am able to add a packaging type AAR but the classes from the lirbary project are not visible/available.

I want to be able to see the referenced classes in my build path for development as currently m2e plugin does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to accomplish this with the newest release of the android-maven-plugin

**v 3.8.2 that supports and integrates AAR library packaging**

In order to **use the generated Library files within your ADT workspace**: 
Add the generated folder from target/unpacked-libs as source folder to work with while developing.

**BuildPath-> Use as source folder**

If someone has a better way to doing this please share..

Maven 3.1.1+

**Sample Maven Configuration:**

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${android-maven-plugin-version}</version>
            <goals>
                <goal>consume-aar</goal>
            </goals>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android-platform}</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```